# Why don't I have to accept a EULA when installing Adobe Flash Player?

Tags: flash, proprietary, license

The Adobe Flash Player has a [quite restrictive EULA](http://www.adobe.com/products/eulas/pdfs/PlatformClients_PC_WWEULA_Combined_20100108_1657.pdf) but it is not presented to the user when he installs it. Isn't the user obliged to accept it, before using it? Maybe some users would refuse using it, if they knew the rules they accept by installing the Flash Player? (I think same problem applies to many software from partner repository, restricted drivers and proprietary or non-free software.)

Comment: Note that you _do_ have to accept a EULA when installing Microsoft's core web-fonts, interestingly.

Comment: US users are obliged to accept it. Checkbox licenses are not necessarily valid and legal everywhere.

Comment: The status of `EULA` itself is not very clear in every jurisdiction. I mean to say, that `legality` of EULA is a gray area in many jurisdictions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is implied You have accepted the EULA by installing the flash plugin from the software center.

You are shown this warning in the software center. 
[image]

Comment: What about installing it using apt-get or synaptic?

Comment: totally disagree. It is there, and the fact you do not like it does not mean it's useless.

Comment: +1 Lo'oris, and moreover, what about servers, where is no GUI available, and you have to use apt-get aptitude or something similar, and not usc nor synaptic.

Comment: @rafalcieslak you don't need to install flash on servers or where a gui is not available.